# Tseitin conversion

Tags: boolean-computation, tseitin, cnf

Do you know if the [`Tseitin method`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation) is implemented in Mathematica for converting a formula in CNF ? I didn't find it as a parameter of conversion type in BooleanConvert function. Thank you.

Comment: I am pretty sure BooleanConvert does not introduce new variables, so it cannot use that method.

Comment: yes effectively